# Could you produce electricity from the alpha rays emitting from Americium-241?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

I was just wondering if you could take a small amount of Am<sup>241</sup> and use the gamma rays coming off of it to generate electricity. I don't really know how this would work, so that's why I'm asking it here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You refer to both alpha and gamma radiation. Are you imagining using the charged alpha particles leaving the metal as a source of positive current? Or are you imagining enclosing the americium in some radiation shield and using the heat to boil water and turn a steam turbine? The ionization current in a smoke detector works via a third mechanism, which you can look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can just absorb the radiation as heat and use it to generate electricity thermoelectrically. This is how the Voyager space probes maintain power, for example. This is also mentioned on the [wikipedia page for Am241](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americium-241#RTG_power_generation).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an un-canned 2n3055 transistor to collect the radiation to produce a very small amount of electricity.  I am currently trying to run a very small electrical device on the power. Just for fun

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).